# Buscar palabras en una cadena de texto con PHP

Tags: php

Este es mi codigo:

```
$buscarSemana = array("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes");
$posicionCoincidencia = strpos("Viernes, agosto 14", in_array($buscarSemana));

if ($posicionCoincidencia === false) {
  echo "NO se ha encontrado la palabra.";
} else {
  echo "Éxito! Se ha encontrado la palabra.";
}
```

La cadena de texto puede variar:

```
Viernes, agosto 14
Viernes, agosto 21
Jueves, agosto 27
```

Necesito saber si alguna de las palabras del array $buscarSemna (Lunes, Martes, Miércoles,...) se encuentra en la cadena de texto.

Comment: ¿Quieres comprobar si en el array existe `Viernes`, o `agosto` o `14`? ¿Tiene que ser case sensitive? Por favor explica con claridad lo que se requiere, faltan detalles en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta que hagas un bucle para recorrer el array y comparar con tu cadena. Sería de la siguiente forma:

```
$buscarSemana = array("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes");
$encontrado = false;

foreach ($buscarSemana as $valor) {
   $posicionCoincidencia = strpos("Viernes, agosto 14", $valor);
   if ($posicionCoincidencia !== false) $encontrado=true;
}

if ($encontrado) {
   echo "Éxito! Se ha encontrado la palabra.";
} else {
   echo "NO se ha encontrado la palabra.";
}
```

Observa la dinámica, la variable $valor va tomando los distintos valores del array y lo que hacemos es comparar cada valor con nuestra cadena. Si encontramos una coincidencia hacemos que nuestro marcador $encontrado sea verdadero.

Comment: `strpos()` devuelve la posición numérica o FALSE si no encuentra, En este caso va a devolver 0 que es la posición de la primera letra del día. Y 0 !== TRUE. Tu solución no sirve

Comment: Siempre me regresa: NO se ha encontrado la palabra.

Comment: Porque 0 es diferente de true de modo que no funciona el código. Por favor revisa el manual **[strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos)** está en español. **Nota:** Al comparar se debe hacer `$posicionCoincidencia !== FALSE` porque el comparador débil haría que 0==FALSE y tampoco encontraría el valor

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea Correcto, faltó cambiar los echo o bien el comparador. Gracias.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. Listo. Te quité el voto negativo y te dí el +1. Noto que también quitaste el marcador de paso por referencia `&` que no era pertinente en ese lugar. Pero aún hace falta que quites la parte equivocada de la respuesta porque da lugar a confusiones.

Comment: @quevedo Gracias.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. Quitaste al revés. Dejaste el que no funciona y eliminaste la corrección que si funcionaba

Comment: @quevedo, Gracias por tu paciencia y comentarios; es verdad y es que después del trabajo no está la mente muy lúcida.

Comment: @AntonioS.F. Es típico. No te preocupes que para ayudarnos estamos